# Swift 3 convert String from isoLatin1 to utf8

Tags: swift, string, swift3, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I need to convert an ISO-8859-1 (isoLatin1) encoded XML string to UTF-8. I tried some code I found on other questions, but most of them covers converting string to utf8 and vice-versa. I don't have any code, so none will be posted.

Sorry, to make it clear, I tried:

`String(data:isoLatin1EncodedData, encoding: .uf8)` is `nil`
`String(data:isoLatin1EncodedData, encoding: .isoLatin1)` returns the string with the wrong encoding.

`String(utf8String: isoLatin1EncodedString.cString(using: String.Encoding.isoLatin1)!)` is `nil`

I need the string with to be converted from one encoding to another...
Edit2: Sample feed - http://feeds.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091.xml

Comment: Use the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1418413-init, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/string.encoding/1780189-isolatin1 and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1538904-withcstring

Comment: @Palle, none of these links help, string ends being `nil`, or with the same encoding as before...

Comment: Can you provide sample isoLatin1 string that you would like to convert ?

Comment: @user1046037 added link...

Comment: I get 404 error, but could `SEGUNDA, 18 DE SETEMBRO DE 2017` be used as a sample ?

Comment: Some samples: `'Não tenho ai-ai-ai, ui-ui-ui'`, `Janaína Paschoal fica em último` and `Preparador Nuno Cobra deixará prisão`... The problem arises with these accentuation, like á, à, é, ã, etc... They are displayed wrong if the encoding isn't converted...

Comment: But those strings are not `.isoLatin1`. Can you provide an actual Xcode project that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Sharing an project will be a little hard now, and since people are downvoting this question, I will close it, and later, when I upload a project to github, I create a new, more detailed question. Thanks to everyone who tried to help...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for:

## Code:

```
let inputString = String("Não tenho ai-ai-ai, ui-ui-ui")

if let data = inputString.data(using: .isoLatin1),
    let convertedString = String(data: data, encoding: .isoLatin1) {

    print("convertedString = \(convertedString)")
}
else {
    print("Something went wrong in conversion")
}
```

## Output:

```
convertedString = Não tenho ai-ai-ai, ui-ui-ui
```

Answer (score 0):

The string returned by your url is isoLatin1. You can try this in a Playground and verify it yourself:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let url = URL(string:"http://feeds.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091.xml")!

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    print(data ?? "")   // "16646 bytes\n"
    guard let data = data else {
        print(error ?? "none")
        return
    }
    if let attStr = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.isoLatin1.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil) {
        print(attStr.string)   // "http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/ Primeiro jornal em tempo real em língua portuguesa pt-br Copyright Folha de S.Paulo. Todos os direitos reservados. http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/folha/conheca/arquivo_e_copyright.shtml webmaster@grupofolha.com.br (Webmaster Folha de S.Paulo) colunas/monicabergamo/ http://f.i.uol.com.br/folha/furniture/5.2/images/lgo-folha_de_spaulo-167x31.gif http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/ 88 31 Primeiro jornal em tempo real em língua portuguesa http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1919007-nao-tenho-ai-ai-ai-ui-ui-ui-diz-tony-ramos-sobre-proximidade-dos-70.shtml <b>Tony Ramos</b> conta que sua reação à <a href="http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/poder/2017/09/1917256-joesley-batista-e-ricardo-saud-se-apresentam-a-pf-em-sao-paulo.shtml">prisão</a> do empresário Joesley Batista, da JBS, no domingo (10), foi &quot;como a de qualquer brasileiro. Primeiro, um susto. Depois, você fica triste. E então espera que a Justiça faça o seu serviço&quot;. <a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1919007-nao-tenho-ai-ai-ai-ui-ui-ui-diz-tony-ramos-sobre-proximidade-dos-70.shtml">Leia mais</a> (09/17/2017 - 02h00) 17 Sep 2017 02:00:00 -0300 http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1919022-prefeitura-autoriza-instalacao-de-bandeiras-do-brasil-nas-marginais.shtml O advogado José Marcelo Braga Nascimento, que encabeça a campanha &quot;Embandeirando São Paulo&quot;, recebeu autorização da prefeitura para instalar mastros com a bandeira nacional em 26 pontes das marginais Tietê e Pinheiros. Ele já tinha conseguido instalar outras iguais na avenida Brasil. <a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1919022-prefeitura-autoriza-instalacao-de-bandeiras-do-brasil-nas-marginais.shtml">Leia mais</a> (09/16/2017 - 02h00) 16 Sep 2017 02:00:00 -0300 http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1918981-miller-e-acionado-na-justica-sobre-caso-que-envolve-o-mpf-e-a-embraer.shtml O <a href="http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/poder/2017/09/1918114-pf-encontra-mensagens-de-miller-e-aponta-ligacao-com-gabinete-de-janot.shtml">ex-procurador Marcello Miller</a> está sendo questionado, na Justiça, por sua atuação em outro caso rumoroso: a assinatura, em 2016, de um termo de ajustamento de conduta entre o Ministério Público Federal, que ele representava, e a Embraer. Um ex-diretor da empresa o acusa de atuação indevida no processo. <a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1918981-miller-e-acionado-na-justica-sobre-caso-que-envolve-o-mpf-e-a-embraer.shtml">Leia mais</a> (09/16/2017 - 02h00) 16 Sep 2017 02:00:00 -0300 http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1918965-janaina-paschoal-fica-em-ultimo-lugar-em-concurso-para-professor-titular-da-usp.shtml A advogada Janaína Paschoal foi a última colocada em um concurso que escolheu os dois novos professores titulares de direito penal da Faculdade de Direito da Universidade de São Paulo. <a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1918965-janaina-paschoal-fica-em-ultimo-lugar-em-concurso-para-professor-titular-da-usp.shtml">Leia mais</a> (09/15/2017 - 20h09) 15 Sep 2017 20:09:00 -0300 http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1918588-vereadores-de-sp-pedem-que-mpf-investigue-mostra-cancelada.shtml A bancada cristã da Câmara Municipal de SP fez um requerimento que pede que o Ministério Público Federal apure &quot;ilícitos penais&quot; e &quot;atos de improbidade administrativa&quot; por parte do Ministério da Cultura, de executivos do Santander e do curador da <a href="http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/ilustrada/2017/09/1917600-curador-de-mostra-cancelada-diz-que-banco-infringiu-regras-basicas.shtml">mostra &quot;Queermuseu&quot;</a>. <a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1918588-vereadores-de-sp-pedem-que-mpf-investigue-mostra-cancelada.shtml">Leia mais</a> (09/15/2017 - 02h00) 15 Sep 2017 02:00:00 -0300 http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1918438-reacao-do-mercado-enfraquece-tese-de-que-jf-quebrara-sem-wesley-e-joesley.shtml A reação positiva do mercado em relação à troca de comando na J&amp;F enfraquece o principal argumento de <a href="http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1918087-joesley-batista-desconfia-que-pode-ser-traido-por-ricardo-saud.shtml">Joesley Batista</a> para conseguir o perdão judicial: sem ele e sem o <a href="http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/poder/2017/09/1918304-eu-me-vi-em-panico-disse-wesley-batista-em-audiencia-apos-ser-preso.shtml">irmão Wesley</a> à frente da empresa, ela poderia quebrar. <a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1918438-reacao-do-mercado-enfraquece-tese-de-que-jf-quebrara-sem-wesley-e-joesley.shtml">Leia mais</a> (09/15/2017 - 02h00) 15 Sep 2017 02:00:00 -0300 http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1918459-preparador-nuno-cobra-deixara-prisao.shtml O preparador físico Nuno Cobra deve deixar a carceragem da Polícia Federal de São Paulo, onde está preso desde a <a href="http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/cotidiano/2017/09/1917460-preparador-fisico-nuno-cobra-e-preso-por-crime-sexual-em-voo.shtml">segunda (11)</a>, nas próximas horas. <a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1918459-preparador-nuno-cobra-deixara-prisao.shtml">Leia mais</a> (09/14/2017 - 16h51) 14 Sep 2017 16:51:00 -0300 http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1918386-morre-em-sp-o-jornalista-fernando-pacheco-jordao-autor-de-dossie-herzog.shtml O jornalista Fernando Pacheco Jordão morreu nesta quinta (14), em São Paulo, aos 80 anos. <a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1918386-morre-em-sp-o-jornalista-fernando-pacheco-jordao-autor-de-dossie-herzog.shtml">Leia mais</a> (09/14/2017 - 12h03) 14 Sep 2017 12:03:00 -0300 http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1918236-ex-presidente-da-eletronuclear-preso-em-2015-opera-cancer-de-pele.shtml O ex-presidente da Eletronuclear Othon Luiz Pinheiro da Silva foi operado na quarta (13) de um câncer de pele, no hospital da Marinha no Rio de Janeiro. Aos 78 anos e condenado a 43 anos de prisão, o vice-almirante, considerado o pai do programa nuclear brasileiro, está <a href="http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/poder/2015/08/1665550-juiz-da-lava-jato-decreta-prisao-preventiva-de-almirante-e-executivo.shtml">detido</a> em uma unidade militar desde julho de 2015. Em janeiro, ele tentou o suicídio. <a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1918236-ex-presidente-da-eletronuclear-preso-em-2015-opera-cancer-de-pele.shtml">Leia mais</a> (09/14/2017 - 02h00) 14 Sep 2017 02:00:00 -0300 http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1918087-joesley-batista-desconfia-que-pode-ser-traido-por-ricardo-saud.shtml O clima entre os delatores da J&amp;F é de desconfiança. Joesley Batista e seu irmão, Wesley, acreditam que o executivo Ricardo Saud pode traí-los caso a <a href="http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/poder/2017/09/1917324-definicao-sobre-futuro-da-delacao-da-jbs-pode-ficar-com-raquel-dodge.shtml">negociação</a> com o Ministério Público Federal para preservar benefícios que obtiveram no acordo de delação premiada naufrague. <a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1918087-joesley-batista-desconfia-que-pode-ser-traido-por-ricardo-saud.shtml">Leia mais</a> (09/14/2017 - 02h00) 14 Sep 2017 02:00:00 -0300 http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1917896-luiza-brunet-e-ex-se-cumprimentam-mas-audiencia-de-conciliacao-fracassa.shtml A atriz Luiza Brunet se reencontrou com o ex, Lírio Parisotto, na segunda (11), na 4ª Vara da Família e Sucessões. Os dois se cumprimentaram de forma polida - mas a audiência de conciliação entre eles foi um fracasso. <a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1917896-luiza-brunet-e-ex-se-cumprimentam-mas-audiencia-de-conciliacao-fracassa.shtml">Leia mais</a> (09/13/2017 - 02h00) 13 Sep 2017 02:00:00 -0300 http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1917891-para-criminalistas-82888288saida-para-joesley-pode-ser-anular-processo-de-delacao.shtml A defesa dos delatores da J&amp;F tem pouca esperança de manter a delação deles integralmente em pé. Se a repactuação dos benefícios com a PGR (Procuradoria-Geral da República) não evoluir a contento, a saída para <a href="http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/poder/2017/09/1917396-joesley-deixa-carceragem-da-pf-em-sp-e-segue-para-brasilia.shtml">Joesley Batista e Ricardo Saud,</a> entendem advogados criminalistas, seria partir para o tudo ou nada e tentar anular todo o processo. <a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1917891-para-criminalistas-82888288saida-para-joesley-pode-ser-anular-processo-de-delacao.shtml">Leia mais</a> (09/13/2017 - 02h00) 13 Sep 2017 02:00:00 -0300 http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1917885-rodrigo-maia-diz-que-nao-vai-ser-facil-negociar-a-reforma-da-previdencia.shtml O presidente da Câmara dos Deputados, Rodrigo Maia (DEM-RJ), afirma que só depois da passagem do &quot;furacão&quot; que deve ser a votação da segunda denúncia contra Michel Temer será possível negociar com as lideranças no parlamento se a reforma da Previdência será ou não votada. Mesmo assim, as tratativas não serão nada fáceis. <a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1917885-rodrigo-maia-diz-que-nao-vai-ser-facil-negociar-a-reforma-da-previdencia.shtml">Leia mais</a> (09/13/2017 - 02h00) 13 Sep 2017 02:00:00 -0300 http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1917677-fhc-e-cardozo-serao-testemunhas-de-defesa-de-lula-nesta-terca-feira-em-sp.shtml O ex-presidente Fernando Henrique Cardoso será mais uma vez testemunha de defesa de Lula em um processo. <a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1917677-fhc-e-cardozo-serao-testemunhas-de-defesa-de-lula-nesta-terca-feira-em-sp.shtml">Leia mais</a> (09/12/2017 - 07h10) 12 Sep 2017 07:10:00 -0300 http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1917580-joao-carlos-martins-viajara-pelo-brasil-para-formar-orquestras.shtml <b>PARTITURA</b><br/> A Fundação Bachiana Filarmônica, do maestro João Carlos Martins, teve seu plano de atividades de 2018 aprovado na Lei Rouanet. Estão previstos 28 concertos durante o ano, 22 deles gratuitos, além de cursos de música para jovens e crianças. O total do incentivo é de R$ 4,3 milhões. <a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1917580-joao-carlos-martins-viajara-pelo-brasil-para-formar-orquestras.shtml">Leia mais</a> (09/12/2017 - 02h00) 12 Sep 2017 02:00:00 -0300 \n"
    }
}.resume()
```

---

As I said your string will always be unicode (UTF-8) but you can convert the data to any encoding. For instance:

```
let url = URL(string:"http://feeds.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091.xml")!
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    print(data ?? "")   // "16355 bytes" isoLatin1 data size
    guard let data = data else { print(error ?? "none")
        return
    }
    let string = String(data: data, encoding: .isoLatin1) ?? "" // data is Latin1
    print(string)                          // prints OK string is always UTF8
    let isoLatin1Data = string.data(using: .isoLatin1)   // 16355 bytes OK
    print(isoLatin1Data == data)                         // true
    let utf8Data = Data(string.utf8)                     // 16498 bytes
    let string2 = String(data: utf8Data, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
    print(string == string2)                             // true
    print(Data(string.utf8) == Data(string2.utf8))       // true
}.resume()
```

---

The resulting String is:

```
// <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
```

Folha de S.Paulo - Colunas - Mônica Bergamo
http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/
Primeiro jornal em tempo real em língua portuguesa
pt-br
Copyright Folha de S.Paulo. Todos os direitos reservados.
http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/folha/conheca/arquivo_e_copyright.shtml
webmaster@grupofolha.com.br (Webmaster Folha de S.Paulo)
colunas/monicabergamo/

Folha de S.Paulo - Colunas - Mônica Bergamo
http://f.i.uol.com.br/folha/furniture/5.2/images/lgo-folha_de_spaulo-167x31.gif
http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/
88
31
Primeiro jornal em tempo real em língua portuguesa

Equipe de Alckmin vê Doria 'louco' com pesquisa
http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/10/1924066-geraldo-alckmin-e-michel-temer-ensaiam-reaproximacao.shtml

O governador Geraldo Alckmin (PSDB-SP) se reuniu com seu staff político e de comunicação no domingo para analisar os números do <a href="http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/poder/2017/10/1923269-forca-eleitoral-de-lula-resiste-apos-condenacao-na-lava-jato.shtml">Datafolha</a&gt; e de pesquisas feitas por sua equipe, por telefone, cujos números coincidem com o do instituto. Concluíram que, com o empate dele com João Doria, o prefeito vai &quot;enlouquecer&quot; e intensificar a campanha para ser candidato a presidente.
<a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/10/1924066-geraldo-alckmin-e-michel-temer-ensaiam-reaproximacao.shtml">Leia mais</a> (10/04/2017 - 02h00)
04 Oct 2017 02:00:00 -0300


Diplomata que criticou Temer é removido de consulado em NY
http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/10/1924064-diplomata-que-criticou-temer-e-removido-de-consulado-em-ny.shtml

O diplomata Julio de Oliveira Silva foi removido na terça (3) do cargo de segundo-secretário do consulado do Brasil em NY pelo chanceler Aloysio Nunes Ferreira (PSDB-SP). Ele não recebeu aviso prévio nem explicação para a transferência e soube dela pelo Diário Oficial.
<a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/10/1924064-diplomata-que-criticou-temer-e-removido-de-consulado-em-ny.shtml">Leia mais</a> (10/04/2017 - 02h00)
04 Oct 2017 02:00:00 -0300


Ministro da Justiça quer mudar classificação indicativa no país
http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/10/1924062-ministro-da-justica-quer-mudar-classificacao-indicativa-no-pais.shtml

O ministro da Justiça, Torquato Jardim, quer mudar o sistema de classificação indicativa no Brasil. &quot;Vamos continuar tendo uma repartição em Brasília para dizer a idade em que se pode assistir a novela e cinema no país? É uma loucura. Está na hora de a sociedade assumir isso&quot;, diz ele.
<a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/10/1924062-ministro-da-justica-quer-mudar-classificacao-indicativa-no-pais.shtml">Leia mais</a> (10/04/2017 - 02h00)
04 Oct 2017 02:00:00 -0300


Planos de saúde perderam 700 mil usuários no último ano, diz associação
http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/10/1923878-planos-de-saude-perderam-700-mil-usuarios-no-ultimo-ano-diz-associacao.shtml

Os planos de saúde perderam 700 mil usuários em agosto em comparação com o mesmo mês de 2016. Só em São Paulo foram 370 mil clientes a menos, segundo levantamento da FenaSaúde, associação que representa as maiores operadoras do setor e que credita a queda à crise.
<a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/10/1923878-planos-de-saude-perderam-700-mil-usuarios-no-ultimo-ano-diz-associacao.shtml">Leia mais</a> (10/03/2017 - 11h50)
03 Oct 2017 11:50:00 -0300


Defesa acredita que Palocci passará o Natal em casa
http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/10/1923730-defesa-acredita-que-palocci-passara-o-natal-em-casa.shtml

A defesa de Antonio Palocci acredita que o ex-ministro da Fazenda passará o Natal em casa. Ainda que, depois de fechado o acordo de delação premiada, ele tenha que passar mais um tempo preso, a esperança é que seja beneficiado com a permissão para comemorar a data em casa, com a família.
<a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/10/1923730-defesa-acredita-que-palocci-passara-o-natal-em-casa.shtml">Leia mais</a> (10/03/2017 - 02h00)
03 Oct 2017 02:00:00 -0300


Vídeo sobre exposição gera tensão entre Doria e o MAM
http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/10/1923727-video-sobre-exposicao-gera-tensao-entre-e-doria-e-o-mam.shtml

A <a href="[http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/ilustrada/2017/09/1923259-em-video-joao-doria-condena-mostra-queermuseu-e-performance-no-mam.shtml">manifestação</a&gt](http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/ilustrada/2017/09/1923259-em-video-joao-doria-condena-mostra-queermuseu-e-performance-no-mam.shtml">manifesta%C3%A7%C3%A3o</a&gt); de João Doria contra a <a href="http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/ilustrada/2017/09/1922810-na-internet-museu-e-acusado-de-pedofilia-apos-performance-com-nudez.shtml">performance do MAM</a> (Museu de Arte Moderna) que mostrava um homem nu surpreendeu e causou desconforto aos diretores da instituição. Eles esperavam que o tucano se posicionasse na linha da defesa da liberdade de expressão.
<a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/10/1923727-video-sobre-exposicao-gera-tensao-entre-e-doria-e-o-mam.shtml">Leia mais</a> (10/03/2017 - 02h00)
03 Oct 2017 02:00:00 -0300


Vanderlei Luxemburgo depõe como testemunha de defesa de filho de Lula
http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/10/1923584-vanderlei-luxemburgo-depoe-como-testemunha-de-defesa-de-filho-de-lula.shtml

<a href="http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/poder/2017/08/1906136-lula-chama-ex-presidentes-franceses-como-testemunhas-de-defesa.shtml">Vanderlei Luxemburgo</a>, técnico do Sport, vai depor na tarde desta segunda (2) como testemunha de defesa de <a href="http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/poder/2015/10/1698829-filho-de-lula-levou-r-15-mi-de-forma-muito-suspeita-diz-procuradoria.shtml">Luis Cláudio Lula da Silva</a>, filho do ex-presidente Lula, em processo da Operação Zelotes.
<a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/10/1923584-vanderlei-luxemburgo-depoe-como-testemunha-de-defesa-de-filho-de-lula.shtml">Leia mais</a> (10/02/2017 - 13h44)
02 Oct 2017 13:44:00 -0300


Deputado pede que CPI faça acareação entre Meirelles e irmãos Batistas
http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/10/1923094-deputado-pede-que-cpi-faca-acareacao-entre-meirelles-e-irmaos-batista.shtml

A CPI da JBS decide nesta semana se submete Henrique Meirelles, ministro da Fazenda, a uma acareação com Joesley e Wesley Batista, donos da empresa. O ministro foi presidente do conselho de administração da J&amp;F, holding do grupo.
<a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/10/1923094-deputado-pede-que-cpi-faca-acareacao-entre-meirelles-e-irmaos-batista.shtml">Leia mais</a> (10/02/2017 - 02h00)
02 Oct 2017 02:00:00 -0300


Delatores da Odebrecht começam a receber intimação do STF
http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/10/1923085-delatores-da-odebrecht-comecam-a-receber-intimacao-do-stf.shtml

Delatores da Odebrecht começaram a receber uma intimação do STF (Supremo Tribunal Federal) sobre os acordos de colaboração que fizeram com a Justiça e passaram a tomar conhecimento das mudanças determinadas por <a href="[http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/poder/2017/01/1854148-carmen-lucia-homologa-77-delacoes-da-odebrecht.shtml">Cármen](http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/poder/2017/01/1854148-carmen-lucia-homologa-77-delacoes-da-odebrecht.shtml">C%C3%A1rmen) Lúcia</a> em cada um deles.
<a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/10/1923085-delatores-da-odebrecht-comecam-a-receber-intimacao-do-stf.shtml">Leia mais</a> (10/02/2017 - 02h00)
02 Oct 2017 02:00:00 -0300


"Tento manter a cabeça pensando que voltarei a andar", diz Lais Souza
http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/10/1923105-tento-manter-a-cabeca-pensando-que-voltarei-a-andar-diz-lais-souza.shtml

<b>O &quot;Tema da Vitória&quot;</b>, música que coroa as conquistas de atletas brasileiros na televisão, toca quando <b>Lais Souza</b>, 28, entra no auditório. A ex-ginasta ajudou a seleção nacional a alcançar resultados históricos nas Olimpíadas de 2004 e 2008. Em 2014, se preparava para representar o país em uma nova modalidade, o esqui, quando sofreu o acidente que a deixou tetraplégica.
<a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/10/1923105-tento-manter-a-cabeca-pensando-que-voltarei-a-andar-diz-lais-souza.shtml">Leia mais</a> (10/01/2017 - 02h00)
01 Oct 2017 02:00:00 -0300


Desafio de Doria é subir na pesquisa, avaliam aliados
http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1923081-desafio-de-doria-e-subir-na-pesquisa-avaliam-aliados.shtml

Secretários de João Doria analisam que ele tem que crescer já nas próximas pesquisas de opinião pública, de institutos com credibilidade, para que sua pré-candidatura à Presidência da República não naufrague antes mesmo de decolar.
<a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1923081-desafio-de-doria-e-subir-na-pesquisa-avaliam-aliados.shtml">Leia mais</a> (09/30/2017 - 02h00)
30 Sep 2017 02:00:00 -0300


Carregador da Receita é preso por furto no shopping 25 de Março
http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1922942-carregador-da-receita-e-preso-por-furto-no-shopping-25-de-marco.shtml

Um prestador de serviço da Receita Federal foi preso durante a <a href="[http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/cotidiano/2017/09/1917384-receita-federal-faz-operacao-para-combater-comercio-clandestino-em-sp.shtml">operação](http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/cotidiano/2017/09/1917384-receita-federal-faz-operacao-para-combater-comercio-clandestino-em-sp.shtml">opera%C3%A7%C3%A3o) que fechou</a> o shopping 25 de Março, no dia 12 de setembro. A detenção foi feita em flagrante depois que um dos comerciantes viu, por câmeras de segurança que acessou pelo celular, o carregador terceirizado roubando uma pochete com R$ 522. A informação foi confirmada pela Receita.
<a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1922942-carregador-da-receita-e-preso-por-furto-no-shopping-25-de-marco.shtml">Leia mais</a> (09/30/2017 - 02h00)
30 Sep 2017 02:00:00 -0300


Caetano Veloso não vai a encontro com Haddad
http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1922903-caetano-veloso-nao-vai-a-encontro-com-haddad.shtml

O cantor Caetano Veloso não estará presente no encontro de artistas hoje com Fernando Haddad, no Rio de Janeiro.
<a href="http://redir.folha.com.br/redir/online/colunas/monicabergamo/rss091/*http://www1.folha.uol.com.br/colunas/monicabergamo/2017/09/1922903-caetano-veloso-nao-vai-a-encontro-com-haddad.shtml">Leia mais</a> (09/29/2017 - 13h52)
29 Sep 2017 13:52:00 -0300


Fernando Haddad encontrará artistas na casa de Caetano Veloso

<-- post text limit

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I droped this for now... But yes, it *is* isoLatin1, but I `need` it in UTF-8, without garbled chars...

Comment: @joaoBeno Once it becomes a string it will be utf8 by default You need to interprete the data when you initialise your string

Comment: btw by using th method above you won't get the characters garbled. It gets the data from the website and uses character encoding isoLatin1 when converting the data to attributed string