# Cannot convert value of type '[String : Date]' to expected argument type '[FileAttributeKey : Any]?'

Tags: swift, xcode9, swift4

when i update code to swift 4 get this error , how i can fix this?
[ERROR SCREEN SHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fiDE.png)

```
      let fullPath = destination.appendingPathComponent(pathString).path

        let creationDate = Date()
        let directoryAttributes = [FileAttributeKey.creationDate.rawValue : creationDate,
                                   FileAttributeKey.modificationDate.rawValue : creationDate]
        do {
if isDirectory {
                try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: fullPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: directoryAttributes )
            }

            else {
                let parentDirectory = (fullPath as NSString).deletingLastPathComponent
                try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: parentDirectory, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: directoryAttributes)
            }
```

Error :

```
Cannot convert value of type '[String : Date]' to expected argument type '[FileAttributeKey : Any]?'
```

other line

```
    let options: [String: Any] = [
        NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey.documentType.rawValue: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
        NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey.characterEncoding.rawValue: NSNumber(value: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    ]
    try self.init(data: data, options: options, documentAttributes: nil)
  }
```

again this error

```
Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type '[NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey : Any]'
```

and other line

```
 let opt = [
         NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey.documentType.rawValue: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
         NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey.characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8
         ] as! [String : Any]

         let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
         returnString = try! NSMutableAttributedString(data:data,options:opt as [String:AnyObject],documentAttributes:nil)

    }
```

ERROR

```
Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to type '[String : AnyObject]' in coercion
```

Comment: You need to show your declaration and initialization of your `directoryAttributes` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `rawValue`. Use the keys as-is in your dictionary:

```
let directoryAttributes = [
    FileAttributeKey.creationDate : creationDate,
    FileAttributeKey.modificationDate : creationDate
]
```

And for the other:

```
let opt: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey: Any] = [
    .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
]
```

Don't use `rawValue` on the keys (though, as demonstrated by Leo in the comments, you do need it for the `utf8` value). And make sure your keys and values are of the proper type. And read the error messages. It tells you what the problem is.

And you also need to change:

```
returnString = try! NSMutableAttributedString(data:data,options:opt as [String:AnyObject],documentAttributes:nil)
```

to:

```
returnString = try! NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options:opt, documentAttributes: nil)
```

Don't needlessly cast, especially to the wrong type.

Comment: If you have a new error unrelated to this original question, you should close off this question by accepting the answer and post a new question about your new issue.

Comment: `.characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8` I know it compiles and should work but it doesn't. You need to pass the rawValue  `.characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue`.

Comment: If you don't add the rawValue you will get `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException` You can check this answer and test yourself removing the rawValue https://stackoverflow.com/a/46270527/2303865