# Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'NSAttributedStringKey'

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, xcode9, swift4, nsattributedstringkey

I am using below code in my project. After update to swift 4 I am getting errors. How can I fix it?

Code:

```
let returnString : NSAttributedString

   if styleList.count > 0
   {
       var attrs = [String:AnyObject]()
       attrs[NSAttributedStringKey.font] = codeFont
       for style in styleList
       {
         if let themeStyle = themeDict[style]
         {
             for (attrName, attrValue) in themeStyle
             {
                 attrs.updateValue(attrValue, forKey: attrName)
             }
         }
     }

     returnString = NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes:attrs )
 }
```

**Here are Errors:**

---

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : AnyObject]' with an index of type 'NSAttributedStringKey'

---

> Cannot convert value of type '[String : AnyObject]' to expected argument type '[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]?'

Comment: The attributes should be of type [NSAttributedStringKey : Any], not [String:AnyObject].

Comment: To give an explanation: `NSAttributedString` is not a subclass of `NSString` as one might think.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri fine working , thanks

Comment: And don't check `if styleList.count > 0` test if it is not empty `!styleList.isEmpty`

Comment: And if you define your attrs type `[NSAttributedStringKey: Any]` as @RamyAlZuhouri said there is no need to use `attrs[NSAttributedStringKey.font] = codeFont` just pass the case `attrs[.font] = codeFont`

Comment: This was explained in my answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46719761/cannot-convert-value-of-type-string-date-to-expected-argument-type-filea).

Answer (score 9):

In swift 4 - NSAttributedString representation is completely changed.

Replace your attribute dictionary `attrs` type `[String:AnyObject]`with `[NSAttributedStringKey:Any]`

Try this:

```
let returnString : NSAttributedString

   if styleList.count > 0
   {
       var attrs = [NSAttributedStringKey:Any]()  // Updated line 
       attrs[NSAttributedStringKey.font] = codeFont
       for style in styleList
       {
         if let themeStyle = themeDict[style]
         {
             for (attrName, attrValue) in themeStyle
             {
                 attrs.updateValue(attrValue, forKey: attrName)
             }
         }
     }

     returnString = NSAttributedString(string: string, attributes:attrs )
 }
```

Here is note from Apple: [NSAttributedString - Creating an NSAttributedString Object](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring)

Comment: Thanks...It worked for me...